# How to copy/move a file fro SFTP to azure blob using function app?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I wanted to move the file residing in the SFTP to Azure blob using Function App. I'm able to move the file through logical app, But I want to use Function app. I have used the external file trigger and given trigger as sftp path, external file input as  sftp path and external file out as azure blob. The file name is sample.xml.
Could anyone help on this?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "in the SFTP"? sftp is a protocol, not a place. I'm not sure, exactly, what you're asking.

Comment: It is the place where I get the file. Here you can find the code which i have used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599311/move-the-file-from-sftp-to-the-azure-container-using-function-app . Thank you

Comment: Why do you have two separate questions when they are directly related? I'm very confused.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In the above question I haven't given the code. For more clarity I have written separate question including the code.

Comment: Then you should close and delete this question. Note: You could have very easily edited this question and added your code, instead of posting a new question.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for the advise. I will delete this post.